# Django: Get a table into Django view

Tags: python, django, datatables

I have Django model that contains data ("Name" and "Status") for 10 people. I display this model in a `DataTable` with checkboxes and if I check a box it changes the Class into `selected`, e.g. `<tr role="row" class="odd selected"`

The user makes a selection from the `DataTable` and press a button ("Send selection by email"). The selection will go into a Django View. I will write code that filter out those contains a `selected`, obtain its PK and send an email with info.

**However, I have problem in the first step, to get the `DataTable` object into the view.**

A similar approach would have been to use a `Multiselect`, but here I want the look of a table and not a form box.

My attempted solution is to put form tags around the `DataTable` and then read the table to filter out all that are `selected`.

Problem I currently have is that I cannot get the `DataTable` into the `views.py`.

So my question is: How do I access the table in Django View?

I have tried both `POST` and `GET` within below, but request object returns as `None`

```js
$('#datatable').DataTable({
  responsive: true,
  columnDefs: [{
    orderable: false,
    className: 'select-checkbox',
    targets: 0
  }],
  select: {
    style: 'multi',
    selector: 'td:first-child',
    // selectRow: true
  },
  order: [
    [1, 'asc']
  ],

  language: {
    searchPlaceholder: 'Search...',
    sSearch: '',
    lengthMenu: '_MENU_ items/page',
  }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/select/1.3.1/js/dataTables.select.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container">

    <form method="post" action="{% url 'product-send2' %}">
      {% csrf_token %}

      <div class="table-wrapper">
        <table class="form-control table display responsive" id='datatable' style="width:100%;">

          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Send</th>
              <th>Name</th>
              <th>Status</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>

          <tbody>
            {% for object in object_list %}
            <tr>
              <td></td>
              <td>{{ object.name }}</td>
              <td>{{ object.status }}</td>
              <tr>
                {% endfor %}

          </tbody>

          <tfoot>
          </tfoot>
        </table>
      </div>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    </form>

  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

In the Urls

```
path('product/send/', send_product2, name='product-send2')
```

and in the views

```
def send_product2(request):
    recipients = request.POST.get('datatable')
    print(recipients)
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/product/list')
```

I have tried variants such as

```
recipients = request.GET.get('datatable')
```

and

```
recipients = request.POST.get('datatable', False)
```

I cannot get hold of the `"object"` and don't really know how to debug it.

In the end, it should work as a multiselect for the form (that will be sent by email).

I hope I can help with some hints how to progress.

Thanks!

When I `print(request.__dict__)` it looks like below

```
: <SimpleLazyObject: <function AuthenticationMiddleware.process_request.<locals>.<lambda> at 0x7f907ab5f680>>, '_messages': <django.contrib.messages.storage.fallback.FallbackStorage object at 0x7f907ab82b10>, '_body': b'csrfmiddlewaretoken=xxx_length=10', '_post': <QueryDict: {'csrfmiddlewaretoken': ['xxxxx'], 'datatable_length': ['10']}>, '_files': <MultiValueDict: {}>, 'csrf_processing_done': True}
```

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to do here. Where is the data for the table coming from?

Comment: Do you want to get the datatable into Django, or into the template?

Comment: Sorry, it was unclear, I have updated the question with a clarification

Comment: But this still isn't clear. You don't have any check boxes in that template.

Comment: sry, was trying to being economic for not cause overload in info, but apparently cause confusion instead.

Answer (score 0):

you can not submit an entire table in a form, especially based on id tag. From the code you posted it looks like you configured your datatable without event handlers.
From: https://editor.datatables.net/examples/inline-editing/submitButton.html

```
dom: "Bfrtip",
    ajax: "../php/staff.php",
    columns: [
        {
            data: null,
            defaultContent: '',
            className: 'select-checkbox',
            orderable: false
        },
        { data: "first_name" },
        { data: "last_name" },
        { data: "position" },
        { data: "office" },
        { data: "start_date" },
        { data: "salary", render: $.fn.dataTable.render.number( ',', '.', 0, '$' ) }
    ],
    order: [ 1, 'asc' ],
    select: {
        style:    'os',
        selector: 'td:first-child'
    },
    buttons: [
        { extend: "create", editor: editor },
        { extend: "edit",   editor: editor },
        { extend: "remove", editor: editor }
    ]
```

and then added a submit button that actually tries to pull all the elements with name tag in the form dom sub-tree and sends those to the back-end.
In order to achieve what you want you need to create a custom event handler in the front-end that is hooked to the checkbox(or use functions integrated in the DataTable plugin) then generate a form on the fly with javascript where you add the relevant information(the pk of the selected record/s I assume). Submitting the newly generated form will result in a valid POST request that you can handle in the view.

Given all above, I would recommend to avoid using such mechanics in general. POST/GET that are not REST based lead to the regeneration of the entire page which is a bad thing to do when dealing with large interactive tables.

Comment: Thanks, need some time to digest before I can give feedback, but in general, if you would do it (let the user make a selection in a list which you later will "analyze") is above the "preferred way" or should I spend time getting up to speed on another solution? thanks

Comment: either way goes, at the end it depends on the scope of your project and the particular case. If you wish to redirect to different page on select, go for this choice, at the end you will render a new page anyway. If you want to switch a label for example, rendering the entire page is an overkill and it will break the user experience.

Comment: ok, had time to look at it now, I cannot really see the solution here. What I am asking for is how to get the selection back into View, for further manipulation with Python code. Ideally a small complete answer with application in Django is desired, ie, show by taking just one value based upon a checkbox mark from the table and transfer that back into view